# Getting logcat from a tester's android device

Tags: android, testing, remote-debugging, logcat

We are having trouble reproducing some bugs in an application we are developing, and so I would like to retrieve logcat logs from a tester's android device.  He isn't testing plugged into a computer, and we don't have regular physical access to his machine as he is testing in another location.

What is the simplest way for him to send us logcat logs after he has experienced a bug?  Please bear in mind he is not a technical professional but he does seem to have a knack for inducing bugs :)

Comment: If you have direct "WiFi" access to his device I can give you a pre-release version of LogRabbit which will let you capture logs over WiFi and even debug over WiFI. I would love the early feedback and it may help you solve a problem. This all assumes you can get physical access to his device and that oyu are using a Mac for development. Just shoot me a message at support@lograbbit.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do AFAIK is to install a Log application, such as:  LogCollector: http://www.appbrain.com/app/log-collector/com.xtralogic.android.logcollector

By this way, tester can send log data to your email or message.

Comment: This app doesn't work on later builds of Android.  Any updates?

Answer (score 2):

A useful tool to collect log messages remotely is [www.remotelogcat.com](http://www.remotelogcat.com) -
it can be used to store strings, or the logcat for the current application.

You need to add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

In order to read logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [PhoneHome](http://mattspitz.me/2013/12/05/phonehome-remote-logging-for-android.html). Will work >= 4.1 without root, essentially inserting a layer between your log calls and logcat...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Download **Logger app** to your device: **Logger - Offline Local Debugging** 
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.rogansky.logger.app
- Download **Logger library** to your project and initialize library

Download and intialize library:

1. Download **Loger library** via dependencies `compile 'sk.rogansky.logger:logger:+'`
2. If you want to automatically send fatal exceptions to **Logger app**, initialize **Logger library** in onCreate in App class (don't forget add class to manifest)

   `public class MyApp extends Application {
       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Log.initialize(getApplicationContext());
            // to send fatal exceptions in RELEASE mode too, initialize Logger with unique string channel Log.initialize(context, channel);
       }
   }`

   Add class to manifest `<application android:name=".MyApp"....`
3. If you want to receive details about network, add permission to manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Logger library has the same interface as java logger, but has some nice features.
After initialization will library automatically send fatal exceptions to Logger app.

You can send your message too. Just add action to call method.

```
import sk.rogansky.logger.Log;

Log.d(Log.Action.SHOW_NOTIFICATION, "TAG", "Message"); 
Log.d(Log.Action.SAVE, "TAG", "Message"); // it will save locally in Logger app
```

Everything works local and offline, but testers can share logs via **Logger app**.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to collect logs without libraries or Log Applications.
You gonna need to create a Process object by executing Runtime command and specifying arguments as:

`new String[]{"logcat", "-v", "threadtime"}`

Then, you could use InputStream from Process to read logs. See this article for example code and more details:
https://medium.com/@danileron/collect-testers-devices-logs-without-libraries-or-third-party-applications-9e6a7e609a2c